# R Linear Regression - Trouble setting values

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am new to R and I need help getting some values from my data set. The information is dollar amounts per each year for a list of cities. I'm trying to setup my values so that I can run a linear regression model on the entire dataset names estimates.

```
estimate <- read.csv("estimate.csv", check.names = FALSE) #Import
estimate

location  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014
city1     200   250   300   500   600
city2     300   300   400   650   780
city3     500   600   700   800   900
```

I am only interested in the data for city3 for the years show.

I know I can just use the code `years <- c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014)` to create my years variable, but I know that is only practical for small tables.

For my linear model I would like to first `plot(years, values)` where the years are columns 2:6 and the values that correspond are from row 3 only. When I run `values <- estimate[3, c(3,2:6]` I get the data for the values but when I try to do the same thing for `years <- estimate[0, c(0,2:6)]` I get a 0 object of 5 variables. Trying to plot that gives me

`Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -In`

Ideally I would like the data setup where:

```
years        values
2010         500
2011         600
2012         700
2013         800
2014         900
```

And I can then run an lm function. Thanks ahead of time. I'm real new at this stuff in R and on Stack so please forgive my newbishness.

Comment: `reshape::melt(estimate)` , then subset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read csv files with `read.csv`, the first row becomes the *names* in your data frame.  Try

```
names = colnames(estimate)
```

You'll see that `names` is a character vector `c("location", "2010", "2011", ...)`.  You can translate this  to `years` by dropping the first item and converting to numeric:

```
years = as.numeric(names[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) extraction** Assuming the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end we can perform the regression like this:

```
year <- as.numeric(names(estimate)[-1])
city3 <- unlist((estimate[3, -1]))
lm(city3 ~ year)
```

**2) melt** or we can convert `estimate` to long form, here 15x3, and then fix up names and make Year numeric and then perform the regression:

```
library(reshape2)

long <- melt(estimate, id = "Location")
names(long) <- c("Location", "Year", "Estimate")
long$Year <- as.numeric(as.character(long$Year))

lm(Estimate ~ Year, long, subset = Location == "city3")
```

**2a) reshape** Converting from wide to long form could also be done without any packages like this:

```
yrs <- names(estimate)[-1]
long <- reshape(estimate, dir = "long", idvar = "Location", 
  varying = list(yrs), times = as.numeric(yrs), timevar = "Year", v.names = "Estimate")

lm(Estimate ~ Year, long, subset = Location == "city3")
```

**Note:**

```
Lines <- "
Location,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014
city1,200,250,300,500,600
city2,300,300,400,650,780
city3,500,600,700,800,900"
estimate <- read.csv(text = Lines, check.names = FALSE)
```